# How do I print oldest file and include its timestamp from a directory via UNIX

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a number of files in a directory, and I would like to print the oldest file along with its timestamp.

The following command is giving me the correct filename, however it does not show me the timestamp.

```
ls -ltr | head -1
```

EDIT: non-gnu based system.

Comment: Do let us know if you are on a GNU based system or a FreeBSD based system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -ltr | head -1 |  awk '{OFS="\t"} {print $6, $7, $8, $9}'
```

awk's print statement takes an index,

If the output of your `ls -ltr` is

`-rw-r--r-- 1 abc abc 185 Dec 19 11:23 testfile.csv`

then

```
 $6: date (19)
 $7: month (Dec)
 $8: time (11:23)
 $9: file name (testfile.csv)
```

index starts with 1 from left to right.

Note: https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.html awk is crazy powerful.

Comment: Not sure what $6 is referring to. Gives me just the following when i run it:162474

Comment: If `-rw-r--r--. Jun 21 14:39 1 user users 990 random_file`  is the output of your `ls -ltr`, then $1 = `-rw-r--r--.` $2 = Jun

Comment: Give me the output of `ls -ltr` I'll give you what index you need

Comment: @GomuGomuZoro Updated the answer, please check.

Comment: -rw-r--r--   1 abc   abc          185 Dec 19 11:23 testfile.csv

Comment: Your answer doesn't work for all valid file names (i.e., for file names containing newlines).

Comment: I really didn't know file names were allowed to have newline characters. may you suggest how to use them in this case?

Comment: Still wont give me the date if I run that command. the problem is as I said ls -1tr | head -1 is not giving me a timestamp. So basically I just get the following: testfile.csv

Comment: It's ls -ltr (the letter 'el' not 'one')

Comment: Yep, I needed to use the letter "el" not "one". Also had to make a small modification for it to work. head -n 2 not head -1 as head -1 was returning a blank line. This worked for me:     ls -ltr | head -n 2 | awk '{OFS="\t"} {print $6, $7, $8, $9}'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stat` to print modification timestamps in seconds since EPOCH and human readable form. Thereafter you can use numerical `sort` on first field and finally `cut` to discard first field.

```
stat -c $'%Y\t%y\t%n' * | sort -nk1 | cut -f 2-
```

---

**EDIT:** TO use to `gnu find`, you can use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T@\t%t\t%p\0' | sort -z -nk1 | cut -z -f2- | head -z -n1; echo
```

Comment: This gives me "Arg list too long" message

Comment: ok try this: `find -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c $'%Y\t%y\t%n' | sort -nk1 | cut -f 2-`

Comment: find: illegal option -- p
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
xargs: illegal option -- 0
xargs: Usage: xargs: [-t] [-p] [-e[eofstr]] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr] [-i[replstr]] [-L #] [-l[#]] [-n # [-x]] [-s size] [cmd [args ...]]

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, it requires `gnu find`.

Comment: Sorry that error is being given when I try the find -print0 command.

Comment: @GomuGomuZoro, is my answer below helpful at all? if not, I can delete it!

Comment: @GomuGomuZoro: Sorry I had a typo. It should have been: `find . -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c $'%Y\t%y\t%n' | sort -nk1 | cut -f 2-` or try my other `find` command as I gave above in answer.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers so far (aside from anubhava's edit, which I either overlooked or was added after I last looked) accommodate file names that contain newlines. However, you don't actually need to see the timestamp for each file to determine which one is the oldest in `bash`. There is a conditional operator, `-ot`, to determine if one file is older than another.

```
oldest=
for f in *; do
  [[ -z $oldest || $f -ot $oldest ]] && oldest=$f
done
ts=$(stat -f %m "$oldest")  # Get the timestamp for the oldest file
```

`stat` is not covered by the POSIX specification, so you'll need to consult your documentation to determine the correct call for your system. (BSD `stat` shown here.)